# Getting VBS to move file

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run through a folder and check the accessed date, if the accessed date is older than 5 days, I need it to move to the "test2" folder and I'm not getting any error messages when ran. Below is what I have so far, can someone point me in the right direction, all I can find on Stack is powershell scripts that do this.

```
Set oFileSys = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


sRoot = "C:\test"                                                               
today = Date                                                                  
nMaxFileAge = 5                                                         

MoveFiles(sRoot)    


        Function MoveFiles(ByVal sFolder) 

            Set oFolder = oFileSys.GetFolder(sFolder)
            Set aFiles = oFolder.Files

            For Each file in aFiles
           FileAccessed = FormatDateTime(file.DateLastAccessed, "2")
                If DateDiff("d", FileAccessed, today) > nMaxFileAge Then
                    oFileSys.MoveFile sFolder, "C:\test2"
                End If
            Next

        End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `oFileSys.MoveFile file, "C:\test2\"` (you got `sFolder` instead of `file`)?

Or you can just `file.move "C:\test2\"` in the if block.

**Update**: You need to put `\` at end of folder name

Comment: I tried both your suggestions PatricK, I do think that was a main problem but it's still not moving the file.  I'll mess around with it some more and see if I can get it.  Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Got it, the string path "sRoot" needed to have a back slash at the end because it couldn't tell whether it was a folder or a file.  thanks.